# Error on Upgrading .NET project from 4.0 to 4.5

Tags: c#, .net-4.5

I have few Web API and WCF services in .NET 4.0
I change the property of each project, change the Target Framework to 4.5,
but I am getting below error.

> The predefined type
>   'System.Runtime.CompilerServices.AsyncVoidMethodBuilder' is defined in
>   multiple assemblies in the global alias; using definition from
>   'c:\Program Files (x86)\Reference
>   Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework.NETFramework\v4.5\mscorlib.dll'   error
>   CS168

Please guide me on this how to remove this

Comment: Go throught the references in each project where that error shows up (and, possibly, in all projects that those projects reference) and look for duplicate references or references with a little warning glyph on their icons. Do you find any? What happens if you remove them?

Comment: Using the wrong reference assemblies is a common mistake.  Especially so a build server, avoiding paying for a VS license is penny wise and three pound foolish.  You'll have to find the project(s) that use c:\windows\microsoft.net\framework instead of the correct c:\program files (x86)\reference assemblies and fix them.

Comment: AsyncVoidMethodBuilder Structure is under the assembly mscorlib (in mscorlib.dll)